# Document edition with changes tracking, on Android

Tags: android, web-apps, document-management, mobile

I want to review the English text of a friend on mobile in a way similar to track changes on Microsoft  Word.

- Android application or a web service or website
- Showing text both on mobile screen and laptop
- Track change feature
- Online document or text sharing

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want Google Docs.

https://www.viwoinc.com/google-docs-has-full-track-changes-word-integration/

If it's not installed by default on your Android device then you can get it here:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.docs.editors.docs&hl=en

Comment: It's good, but does it have track changes feature?

Comment: @Ahmad Yes, please click the first link which is an article about the track changes feature in Google Docs